# Method for saving an HTML canvas image

Tags: image, canvas, save

I’d like to concatenate two or three images (bottom of one to top of next) , and save that image for use on another page (shopping cart page) as a thumbnail.  I've been looking into  using either the HTML5 cache manifest, or the canvas.toDataURL() method.  Which is more suited to this purpose?

I've written code for the toDataURL() method below:

```
<div style="width: 80px;">
    <img id="imageA" src="imageA.jpg" alt="imageA"
        width="70" height="400" >
    <img id="imageB" src="imageB.jpg" alt="imageB" 
        width="70">
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var img1 = document.getElementById("imageA");
        var img2 = document.getElementById("imageB");
        var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
        var context1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
        canvas1.width = "70";
        canvas1.height = "470";
        context1.globalAlpha = 1.0;
        var combinedImage = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 70, 470);  
        var imgURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A cache manifest has no relevance here unless you want to have the images available when off-line, but has no effect when it comes to merging images.

The code shown is not actually drawing the images into the canvas and when you call `getImageData()` you will only get an empty pixel buffer which is not useful here.

Try something like this instead (JavaScript part only):

```
var img1 = document.getElementById("imageA");
var img2 = document.getElementById("imageB");
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var context1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");

canvas1.width = 70;    /// use numbers instead of strings here
canvas1.height = img1.height + img2.height;

/// draw the images onto canvas
context1.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
context1.drawImage(img2, 0, img1.height);

var imgURL = canvas1.toDataURL();  /// defaults to PNG
```

Now your imgURL will contain the concatenated images as a PNG provided CORS requirements are fulfilled (ie. they are on the same server). You should also see the on-screen canvas with the two images embedded.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Ken.  I’m also not clear on how to specify the source location for the image from the shopping cart page.  I assume I can’t just use the imgURL variable since it’s created on a different page.

Comment: @user99330 A different page is ok as long as the page is in the same origin as where the data-uri comes from (origin = domain, port and protocol). If you don't need toDataURL or getImageData on the new page then you can use it from any place.